# The real butcher company

Tags: meaning

> I worked  at Budd Manufacturing where they made auto body parts. It was slave pit, a real butcher shop. They had no decent safety standards...  In desperation for a job, I went walking down Girard Avenue among (the real butcher companies). I saw a black guy lugging hindquarters and loading them onto a truck for Swift's meat company.

Did the real bucher companies sell meat or were their job dangerous to do like Budd Manufacturing?

Comment: https://books.google.co.kr/books?id=YE6YDwAAQBAJ&pg=PT85&lpg=PT85&dq=I+worked+at+Budd+Manufacturing+where+they+made+auto+body+parts.+It+was+slave+pit,+a+real+butcher+shop.+They+had+no+decent+safety+standards.&source=bl&ots=KJPcPae-0Z&sig=ACfU3U0LwE0R1KmJgsuxg5UGm8sJsRb7uQ&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwi8mbvVztLnAhWlBKYKHcegDJUQ6AEwAXoECAYQAQ#v=onepage&q=I worked at Budd Manufacturing where they made auto body parts. It was slave pit%2C a real butcher shop. They had no decent safety standards.&f=false

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It says that Budd made auto parts. So it wasn't an actual butcher shop, but metaphorically it was really dangerous -- the meat cut there was the bodies of the employees since the place had "no decent safety standards." In the US, Swift is a meat packing company, so it was one of the "real butcher companies" that processes animal flesh. You have to distinguish the two different uses of the word real, which isn't easy for beginning learners